# How do I use Any Dice to calculate Mutant Year Zero d66 odds?

Tags: anydice

In Mutant Year Zero, Alien RPG and Forbidden Lands, the designers include a lot of d66 tables, in which a d6 is rolled for the tens and one for the units, giving 36 possible results (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, etc). How would I be able to simulate this in Any Dice?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: What did you try yourself? Showing your own efforts is important, so we can clarify which problems you are facing.

Answer (score 11):

Anydice supports doing arithmetic operations on a die, so you can do this simply by

```
output 10*1d6+1d6
```

or you could construct a "10s d6"

```
output d{10,20,30,40,50,60} + 1d6
```

or a fully custom die

```
output d{11..16, 21..26, 31..36, 41..46, 51..56, 61..66}
```

but only works when you know the outcomes (and their uniformity) and is probably more useful as a method when you have weirder things going on.

Regardless of how you construct the die, if you'll be using it a lot in a computation you'll probably want to define it as a variable so you can call as a roll:

```
SIXSIX: 10 * d6 + d6
output 1dSIXSIX
```

---

Thanks to Carcer and Ilmari Karonen for their inputs

Answer (score 2):

d66 is also used in Maid RPG<sup>[MAID RPG, Introduction p. 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IswWs.png)</sup>. It describes a 6x6 matrix when assigning a fixed order for the dice. d666 is likewise a 3-dimensional matrix of 6x6x6. The chances are of course modeled like this:

```
output d6*10+d6
output d6*100+d6*10+d6
```

However, if the order of the dice is *not* fixed, the results get a little wonky. Let's say we force the smaller one to the front, like we see in the matrix for colors in MAID RPG (it is mirrored around the equals diagonal), then the half-matrix looks like this: There are 15 results that appear twice each (2/36th probability) and 6 that only appear once (1/36th probability). To compensate, you could mirror the 11, 22 and 33 onto 44, 55 and 66, giving you 18 equal distributed results.

```
SIXSIX: {11..16,12..16,22..26,23..26,33..36,34..36,44..46,45,46,55,56,56,66}
output 1dSIXSIX
```

[image: MAID RPG, Step 3: Maid Color Table]